# Find the power series about the origin

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the power series about the origin for the given function $\frac{z^2}{(4-z)^2}$ where |z|< 4. I am lost in the manipulation of the given function to bring it to one of the Taylor series that I know. I am given the following hint: $\frac{1}{(a-z)^2}$ = $\frac{d}{dz}$ (a-z)^(-1). I would appreciate if someone could lead me!

Comment: You want a power series centered at the origin or a power series which is valid for the origin (not necesary centered at $z=0$)??

Comment: centered about the origin

Comment: Hint.  You should be able to write the series for $1/(4-z)$ starting from the geometric series for $1/(1-z)$. Then differentiate term by term and multiply by $z^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression given, is :

$$\frac{z^2}{(4-z)^2} = z^2 \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}(4-z)^{-1}= z^2\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}\left(\frac{1}{4-z}\right)$$

Now, recalling the general geometric series $(1-z)^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k$ for $|z| <1$, you can reach the expression  :

$$\frac{1}{4-z} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty 4^{-(k+1)}z^k, \quad |z| < 4$$

I'll leave this short part up to you.

Finally, this yields us :

$$\frac{z^2}{(4-z)^2} = z^2\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}z}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty 4^{-(k+1)}z^k\right)= z^2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty 4^{-(k+1)}kz^{k-1} = \boxed{\sum_{k=1}^\infty 4^{-(k+1)}kz^{k+1}}$$

Comment: @ElvinJafali This is equivalent to what I reached to. By the way, the index should be $i=1$ due to differentiating.

Comment: @ElvinJafali Check the boxed expression.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to understand your step-by-step solution and thank you!